# How to resize scrollable frame when the window is expanded or maximized?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

When the window is expanded or maximized, the frame is just constant. The size is constant. I want the over all frame to move as I expand or maximize the window. How can this be done?

```
from tkinter import *

def data():
    for i in range(1000):
        if (i % 2) == 0:
            l4 = Label(frame, text="Size of rectangle:")
            l4.grid(row=i, column=0)
        en = Entry(frame)
        en.grid(row=i, column=1)
    b3 = Button(frame, text="Save")
    b3.grid(row=1001, column=0)
    b4 = Button(frame, text="Back")
    b4.grid(row=1001, column=1)

def myfunction(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"),width=250,height=700)
def _on_mousewheel(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(-1*(event.delta/120), "units")   

root=Tk()
sizex = 272
sizey = 707
posx  = 100
posy  = 100
root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))

myframe=Frame(root)
myframe.place(x=0,y=0)

canvas=Canvas(myframe)
frame=Frame(canvas)
myscrollbar=Scrollbar(myframe,orient="vertical",command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)

canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', lambda event: canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units"))

myscrollbar.pack(side="right",fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left")
canvas.create_window((0,0),window=frame,anchor='nw')
frame.bind("<Configure>",myfunction)
data()
root.bind("<MouseWheel>", myfunction)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The canvas will generate a `<Configure>` event when it is resized. You can bind to this event and reset the size of the inner frame to match the width of the canvas when this happens.

However, in your specific case you've got a series of stacked widgets, none of which will grow when you resize the window. Because of that, even when you resize the window, the canvas doesn't grow. Because the canvas doesn't grow, the event won'g fire.

You'll need to use the appropriate options to the geometry managers to make sure the entire hierarchy of windows grows and shrinks appropriately, and then add the binding to set the size of the inner window.

Here's a very basic example. It starts by creating a canvas and packing it so that it fills the root window. It then adds a frame inside the canvas, and arranges for the width of the frame to change whenever the canvas is resized.

```
import tkinter as tk

def handle_canvas_resize(event):
    canvas.itemconfigure(window_id, width=event.width)

def handle_frame_resize(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

inner_frame = tk.Frame(canvas, background="bisque")
window_id = canvas.create_window(2,2, window=inner_frame)
for i in range(1, 101):
    label = tk.Label(inner_frame, text="label #{}".format(i))
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=1, pady=1)

inner_frame.bind("<Configure>", handle_frame_resize)
canvas.bind("<Configure>", handle_canvas_resize)
root.after_idle(canvas.yview_moveto, 0)

root.mainloop()
```